# authentication when testing webservices (SoapUI/jMeter)

Tags: web-services, jmeter, soapui

I am testing some webservices on a page that requires logging in. As it seems access to the wsdl also requires some sort of authentication.

First I tried using SoapUI with basic authorization with user/pass/domain, where user is my application user, pass is user's pass, domain is the application's url.

> user: MyUser
>   pass: MyPass
>   domain: http://my.app.com/home/

The result : #status#   HTTP/1.1 401 Bad credentials

So I tried jMeter's SOAP/XML-RPC Request with basically the same settings and the same result.

Then I added the logging in process as separate steps in the jMeter scenario

> - main page
> - log in
> - soap request

...and the SOAP request succeeded.

Is it possible to set up SoapUI to somehow handle this authentication? 
Or maybe it's possible to fake log in, same as in jMeter?

Comment: Check the raw request. Did the auth credentials make it?

Comment: It seems there is a separate user that has access to webservices only and it has nothing to do with the application user. So, the jMeter version works by accident one could say. There is probably some mumbo jumbo under the hood, so the webservices request is somehow authenticated correctly. When I got hold of that specific webservices user the request went through.

Comment: When it works with usrename, password then you may not have to set the domain. Also check for the test request that WSS Password type as Password Text, see in case if this helps.